# utf-8 to iso-8859-1 encoding problem

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, rss, iso-8859-1

I'm trying preview the latest post from an rss feed on another website. The feed is UTF-8 encoded, whilst the website is ISO-8859-1 encoded. When displaying the title, I'm using;

```
 $post_title = 'Blogging â€“ does it pay the bills?';

 echo mb_convert_encoding($post_title, 'iso-8859-1','utf-8');

 // returns: Blogging ? does it pay the bills?
 // expected: Blogging - does it pay the bills?
```

Note that the hyphen I'm expecting isn't a normal minus sign but some big-ass uber dash. Well, a few pixels longer anyway. :) Not sure how else to describe it as my keyboard can't produce that character...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you mean an Em Dash (—). ISO-8859-1 doesn't include this character, so you aren't going to have much luck converting it to that encoding.

You could use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), but I'd suggest moving off ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 for publication.

Comment: `htmlentities($post_title, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');` should give you an equivalent HTML-string that will be shown correctly in the browser. As it may contain entities (and does in your example) you should not use the string for generating plain-text emails for example.

Comment: You don’t need `htmlentities` when using UTF-8. `htmlspecialchars` will suffice for the HTML special characters `&`, `<`, `>`, `"` and `'`.

Comment: @Gumbo — You do when the character encoding you are outputting doesn't include the characters you want to show.

Answer (score 5):

`mb_convert_encoding` only converts the internal encoding - it won't actually change the byte sequences for characters from one character set to another.  For that you need [iconv](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'ISO-8859-1' );

$post_title = 'Blogging — does it pay the bills?'; // I used the actual m-dash here to best mimic your scenario

echo iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $post_title );
```

Or, as others have said, just convert out-of-range characters to html entities.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the following:

- Your file is actually encoded with UTF-8
- Your editor interprets the file with Windows-1252

The reason for that is that your *EM DASH* character (U+2014) is represented by `â€“`. That’s exactly what you get when you interpret the UTF-8 code word of that character (0xE28094) with [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (0xE2=`â`, 0x80=`€`, 0x94=`”`). So you first need to fix your editor encoding.

And the reason for the `?` in your output is that ISO 8859-1 doesn’t contain the *EM DASH* character.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an em dash (U+2014), and what you're trying to do isn't converting the encoding, because the hyphen is a different character. In other words, you want to search for such characters and replace them manually.

Better yet, just switch the website to UTF-8. It largely coincides with Latin-1 and is more appropriate for a website in 2009.

Comment: *sigh* I totally agree about switching to UTF-8, but the current encoding is a legacy that I've got to tolerate for now... :\

Comment: To be pedantic, only half of Latin-1 has parity with UTF-8 - which is the ASCII half of Latin-1 i.e., any character that fits in 7 bits.  The Latin-1 range from 0x80-0xFF is invalid in UTF-8.  But I agree that converting to UTF-8 is a good idea if possible.