# how to keep the special characters during json encode

Tags: php, json

> $listing_description = "Suitable for working meals and family nights
>   out, Palmers – which is located on Roman Road, has earned an enviable
>   reputation with local food-lovers".

after `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE',$listing_description)` doing this during json encode the dash is replaced by space.

**output**

> Suitable for working meals and family nights out, Palmers  which is
>   located on Roman Road, has earned an enviable reputation with local
>   food-lovers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567100/utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-encoding-problem

Answer (score 0):

**ISO-8859-1** doesn't have a mdash sign so it seems to be impossible to keep it under this encoding

you can change all **mdashes** to some character that iso-8859-1 has using for example [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Before using `iconv` you should add

```
    $listing_description = str_replace("–", html_entity_decode("&#8212;"), $listing_description );
```

Comment: check out the update or just don't use the ido-8859-1 you you don't have to

Comment: i've checked that, but not working and this is ndash;

Comment: ok I've updated it again with using **html_entity_decode** function to keep the mdash as mdash